# Retina scaling options gone when rotating display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

I have a Mid-2014 15" retina MBP with an NVIDIA 750M running 10.12.5. I am outputting to a Dell P2415Q via an mDP to DP cable.

When the display is in landscape (standard) orientation, I get a nice Retina scaling menu like so, the same options that appear for the Macbook display:
[image: Standard orientation resolution options]

When I rotate the display 90 degrees (portrait mode), I get these options:
[image: Portrait orientation resolution options]

I have currently attempted a few solutions. I've played around with SwitchResX. I've run this command:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist DisplayResolutionEnabled -bool true
```

And I've even used the EDID patcher that others have used to force RGB mode on their displays. Option-Clicking the Scaled button gives me resolutions with (low resolution) next to them. I would like to go 1440x2560, but the (low resolution) option looks nowhere near as sharp as the retina scaled 2560x1440 I can set the display to in landscape orientation. If anyone knows how to obtain these scaling options while rotated I would appreciate it.

Comment: SwitchResX didn't work? What wasn't working?

Comment: @JMY1000 Anything, really. The only HiDPI resolutions it lists are 1080x1920 and lower. If I set the resolution to a custom resolution of 1440x2560, it looks the same as the 1440x2560 (low resolution) in the Display settings. If I set it to a scaled resolution of 1440x2560, it looks no different. I am not sure how this program would help me at this point. If there are any specific settings I'm missing please let me know.

Comment: I'll have to check, but I was under the impression you could set up cudtok resolutions and scaling.

Comment: I am having the same problem, any update on this?